# Checking AutocompleteBox if null

Tags: c#

hello I am trying to make a if Statement With Autocompletebox but it's not triggering how I would Like it to. If someone can help me with this it would be great.

Fairly Straight forward, Display message Autocompletebox is null or not. How do i determine if Autocompletebox is empty? or null?

```
if (AutoCompleteBox.SelectedItems == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("it's null");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("it's not null");
    }
}
```

"It's not Null" never fires. I even tried `Autocompletebox == null` How do i set the if statement, such that "it's null" will fire.

Comment: (1) you have an extra close curly brace. (2) Do you really care about null or do you care about the number of items selected? (3) when is this code run, is it in a function or an event?

Comment: Where are you putting this `if()` statement?  Is it only showing "it's not null" or is it not displaying anything at all?

Comment: try `if(AutoCompleteBox.SelectedItems.Count == 0)`

Comment: Sorry I typed the code. Curly brace doesn't play a factor ill edit that. I care about the nulls, the autocompletebox fires on a button.  I even tried to implement this on `public MainWindow(){code...} ` and by default it should show it's null right off the bat but nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectedItems` is a collection, so it should not be null.  As Sudhakar said, you should use

```
if (AutoCompleteBox.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
```

**EDIT:**

Since there is no `Count` method for `RadAutoCompleteBox.SelectedItems`, instead check the `SelectedItem` property:

```
if (AutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem == null)
```

Comment: Definitely Looks like a viable solution, But no count method for RadAutocompletebox.SelectedItems

Comment: Try `if (AutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem == null)` .. the `SelectedItems` collection shouldn't be `null`, but if there is no item selected then `SelectedItem` will be `null`.

Comment: To make the autocompleteboxempty could you also do `AutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem = null` ?

Comment: @user3276954 if you would like to set the `SelectedItem` to `null` then yes, you could use `AutoCompleteBox.SelectedItem = null` but your question was for checking whether or not `SelectedItem` was already `null` so you would need to use the double `==`

Comment: @Albireo, there's a time limit i have to wait